# How often is it neccessary to check the strings of an Eruv?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eruv-chatzerot, time

If you have an Eruv Chatzeros for carrying, how often is it necessary to check it to make sure that it is properly strung and you can still carry on Shabbos?

Comment: A swift surf of the net revealed that the following check their eruvim weekly: Toronto, Phoenix, YU, NW London, LA. There is an interesting document at http://israel613.com/books/ERUV-E.pdf  which quotes the practices of Gedolim in also checking weekly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check any individual string, lechi etc. more often then it would break on average because then you have a chazaka.

Comment: Source would be appreciated!

Comment: Are we assuming a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)?

Comment: Source (and spell-check)?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should check the eruv before every shabbat/day you make use of it.

However, there are those who say that if there is no major weather change you can rely on a chazakah. But I believe this is only for eruvin that are hard to check.  You really should check every Thursday night or Friday before Shabbat.

If it rains or there is a strong wind or snow during shabbat most say you can still use it.

I welcome sources from the community. (My source is from being on an eruv checking committee for a few months)

Comment: I know my local _eruv_'s checkers check it weekly before _Shabas_, but not before _yom tov_ (unless it's a _yom tov_ that coincides with _Shabas_ or is immediately before/after _Shabas_). (_Eruvin_ are important on _yom tov_ also: without an _eruv_, one can't carry anything outside on _yom tov_ unless it's needed on that day; with an _eruv_, one may carry anything outside as long as he's not doing _hachana_. (Of course, CYLOR.))

Comment: On shabbat, anything that isn't needed for the day is muktzeh.... so how can you carry it anywhere?  An eruv does not change what you are allowed to carry... only if you are doing malacha or not.

Comment: Right re _Shabas_, but I was discussing _y"t_.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I've never heard of such a thing as an eruv chetzrot for yom tov.

Comment: Erm, a source for not being allowed to carry outside on _y"t_ when it's not for the same day's benefit? Not at hand, but any _halacha_ book that discusses _m'lacha_ on _y"t_ should have it.

Comment: No, that having an eruv allows you to carry things that you don't need for yom tov. Or that an Eruv on Yom tov does anything at all.

Comment: E.g., _Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah_ 19:1,2,4,7.

Comment: You make it sound like if one checked it on Friday he is NOT relying on chazaka, yet even a kohein would have to rely on chazaka that the nega stayed ke-shiur for the few moments it took him to leave a bayit ha-menugga!

Comment: Double AA, we say Modeh Ani every morning even though there is a chazakah that we woke up the previous 3 days.

Comment: @Avi Those are different kinds of chazakot and maybe you should say Thank You every time you find the eruv kosher too! And anyway I'm just pointing out that you make it sound like relying on a chazaka for the eruv is a bedieved when even checking Friday afternoon makes use of chazaka. As such, it's a numbers game of how long a period of time we assume the strings and such remained the same, and that is going to be related to how sturdy and reliable they are from an engineering perspective. Thus, see my answer below.

Comment: Why do you say there are different kinds of chazakot?